# MongoDB Content Management Web App for the non-technical

Tags: mongodb, content-management-system, keystonejs

When the non-technical people in my team want add some data into the database (MongoDB), they call me to import data with `mongoimport`. While they should do these things by themselves.

So I am looking for a web application that guys without mongodb or other technical background can query, add, delete, edit data in the MongoDB.

The administrator of the web application should create common users.
Common users could manipulate data in database, but couldn't do administrative things.

It should be a common task for a website. But it seems there are no
easy solutions for this requirements.

I've tried [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com/).
However there are 2 problems.

1. Its schema doesn't support nested arrays without ref.
   For example, a person may have many jobs.
   But I have to create a new collection "Jobs", and use ref to relate multiple jobs to a person:
   `jobs: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Jobs' , many: true},`.
   However, I don't want build a new collection, and what I want is:

   ```
   People.add({
     jobs: [{
       name: { type: String, initial: true },
       role: { type: String, initial: true },
       start: { type: Types.Date, initial: true },
       duration: { type: Number, initial: true }
     }]
   });
   ```
2. Its user role system is very weak out-of-box. A user can do anything when "can access keystone" is checked, otherwise nothing.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Wait until those features are integrated https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/257 https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/899 or help us create these features.